# Can somebody explain what is happening in this code. Unable to understand simple oops program

Tags: java, oop

```
interface Foo1 
{ 
  int bar(); 
}

class Sprite 
{
  public int fubar( Foo1 foo ) 
  {
    return foo.bar(); 
  }

  public void testFoo() 
  {
    fubar(
      new Foo1() 
      { 
        public int bar() 
        { 
          return 1;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Unable to understand fubar() method. Can some body explain me this program

Comment: What specifically confuses you?

Comment: Do you have any other class which implemented Foo1 interface??

Comment: The code won't do anything of use btw. It returns a 1 which is wasted. Do you understand 1) interfaces? 2) anonymous inner classes?

Comment: **fubar** method takes the reference value of Foo1 object, calls the method bar() from **foo** reference variable which has **integer** return type and returns the integer value .

Comment: well, it just returns the value which `foo.bar()` will return. It takes a `Foo1` object, calls the `bar`method and returns the result.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: That clue is enough ;)  I understand now its using a anonymous inner class inside a method call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `testFoo` creates an instance of an anonymous inner class that implements the `Foo1` interface and passes it (it actually passes the value of the pointer) to the `fubar` method.

The `fubar` method invokes the `bar` method on the instance of `Foo1` returning the result.

The result for the `fubar` method is ignored in the `testFoo` method.

The net effect is that this code doesn't really do anything as currently shown.

Answer (score 1):

So according to your code, you have one interface called Foo1 which contains one abstract method called `bar()` .

Sprite class has two methods fubar and testFoo.

In your fubar method it gets Foo1 object as a parameter and returns the `foo.bar()` value.

Inisde your testFoo method,you are calling fubar method and you implement the abstract `bar()` method inside it which returns 1 as the integer value.

Still there is no main method in your code ,so there will be no output yet.

this is the overview of your code, if you want more clarifications just inform.